# How can I subset based on smaller than time XYZ?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time

I am trying to create a new data frame that excludes all timestamps bigger/later than 12:00:00. I tried multiple approaches but I keep on having an issue. The time was previously a datetime column that I change to 2 columns, a date and time column (format datetime.time)

**Code:**

[image: Code]

**Issue thrown out:**
[image: Issue thrown out]

Do you have any suggestions to be able to do this properly?

Comment: [Convert column to `DateTime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then you can do greater than operation.

Comment: I just tried via:
df44['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df44['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

when I run it it leads to:
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int

Comment: `12:00` is not a valid python expression. Covert it to a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the solution:

1. change the Datetype from datetime.time to Datetime
2. Use the between method by setting the Datetime column as the index and setting the range

The result is a subset of the dataframe based on the needed time frame.
[image: result]